# How to join the three tables in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am fairly new to Spring Boot. I am trying to join a bunch of tables and get some data back. I have created the entities and repositories for the three tables I am working with. Below is the query I am trying to achieve.

```
                   SELECT *
                   FROM  PEFT_LINE PLI
                   JOIN  PEFT_LINE_RELTN PLICR
                   ON  PLICR.PEFT_LINE_ID   = PLI.PEFT_LINE_ID
                   JOIN  PEFT_CHARGE PC
                   ON  PC.PEFT_CHRG_ID      = PLICR.PEFT_CHRG_ID
```

I have created the entity classes for PEFT_LINE, PEFT_LINE_RELTN and PEFT_CHARGE where PEFT_LINE_RELTN contains the foreign key of both PEFT_LINE and PEFT_CHARGE, and I have established the bidirectional mapping between the three tables.

Entity class for PEFT_LINE

```
            @Entity
            public class PEFT_LINE

            @Id
            private int PeftId;
            private int ProcCode;

            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "PEFT_LINE",fetch =FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
            @JsonManagedReference("PEFT_LINE")
            private List<PEFT_LINE_RELTN> peft_line_reltn;

            ***getters and setters
```

Entity class for PEFT_LINE_RELTN

```
            @Entity
            public class PEFT_LINE_RELTN

            @Id
            private int PeftlineId;
            private int ActiveCd;
            
            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name = "fk_peftId")
            @JsonBackReference("PEFT_LINE")
            private PEFT_LINE peftItem;

            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name = "fk_peftchrgId")
            @JsonBackReference("PEFT_CHARGE")
            private PEFT_CHARGE peftCharge;

            ..getters and setters
```

Entity class for PEFT_CHARGE

```
            @Entity
            public class PEFT_CHARGE

            @Id
            private int PeftchrgId;
            private int ActiveCode;
            
            @OneToMany(mappedBy ="PEFT_CHARGE",fetch =FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
            @JsonManagedReference("PEFT_CHARGE")
            private List<PEFT_LINE_RELTN> peft_line_reltn
            **getters and setters
```

PEFT_LINE Repository

```
            public interface PEFT_LINERepo extends JpaRepository<PeftId, Integer>{
                 
            }
```

I am trying to store the data in the tables. Firstly, when I am trying to send the peft_line request structure such that the peft_line_reltn foreign key also get's inserted.
Request structure for peft_line

```
                          [
                          {
                            "PeftId" : 44,
                            "ProcCode" : 96,
                                "peft_line_reltn":[
                                                   {
                                                    "PeftlineId" : 652,
                                                    "ActiveCd" : 1
                                                   }          
                                                  ]
                           }
                           ]
```

This successfully inserts in both pft_line and pft_line_reltn table

```
                     After insertion
                     pft_line
                     PeftId     ProcCode
                      44           96

                     pft_line_reltn
                     PeftlineId    ActiveCd    fk_peftId    fk_peftchrgId
                      652              1           44            null

                    Request structure for peft_charge
                           [
                           {
                             "PeftchrgId" : 57,
                             "ActiveCode" : 79,
                             "peft_line_reltn":[
                                                 {
                                                   "PeftlineId" : 652,
                                                   "ActiveCd" : 1
          
                                                 }         
                                                 ]
                           }
                           ]

                        After insertion
                        peft_charge table
                        PeftchrgId    ActiveCode
                          57              79

                        pft_line_reltn table
                        PeftlineId    ActiveCd    fk_peftId    fk_peftchrgId
                            652              1           null            57
```

When the insertion happens in the PEFT_LINE_RELTN the foreign key fk_peftId will be stored as null. Please let me know if I am missing out anything here or is there another way to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Table schemas:

```
          PEFT_LINE : PeftId(Primary key)

          PEFT_LINE_RELTN : PeftlineId(Primary key) 
          fk_peftId(foreign key)
          fk_peftchrgId(foreign key)

          PEFT_CHARGE : PeftchrgId(Primary key)
```

Comment: You are having a `@ManyToMany` relationship there. Why not map it as such?

Comment: Thank you @XtremeBaumer.. I will surely try in that way.